# Use PHP To Fill In Named fields in PDF (Ideally on Linux Server)

Tags: php, linux

I have a PDF that has named fields - I'm looking to use PHP on Linux (for a web application) to fill variable data into my PDF with prenamed fields.

In the past I did this on .NET with this product, but I'm looking to do this on Linux - https://www.websupergoo.com/products.aspx#abcpdf

Does anyone have any suggestions on a library or product to do this? I see a lot of depreciated products out there, but looking for something that can be used in production with support.

Thanks in advance for your help!

-NJ

I tried a number of PHP libraries, but most have been depreciated  - none that I've found so far have allowed me to post to fields on Linux.

Comment: I know PDFtk can do it. You would create an FDF file with your form data then call pdftk to apply it to the PDF. This is not a pure PHP solution however as it requires the external pdftk binary which you would need to call via `exec()` or similar.

Comment: Thanks cOle2! I saw that one - it looks great, but it looks like it's not being supported anymore. What do you think?

Comment: FPDI  allows you to import an existing PDF file and use it as a template, while FPDF is creating new PDFs from scratch. Together, these libraries allow you to import an existing PDF with pre-named fields, and then fill in the fields with variable data....                                                              FPDI: https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/
FPDF: http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: @njCoder If you need support there are commercial options, ie https://appligent.com/server-software/fdfmerge-lite/ but pdftk + php-pdftk would be my choice to start with.